# Subquery Returns Data with different order in each Environment

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle SQL query when run in PROD it gives different results(order) than other environments(DEV,UAT). Below is the sample code:

```
SELECT xmlelement("MainMenu",
   xmlagg(xmlelement("MenuItem",
              xmlelement("MenuId", MNI.id),
                (SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement("SubMenu",  xmlelement("MenuItem",
                                             xmlelement("MenuId", MN2.id),
                                             xmlelement("RoleId", MN2.role_id)
                                             
                                             )
                                                   )
                                       )
                          FROM MENU MN2, MROLE RMN2
                          WHERE MN2.id = RMN2.menu_id
                          AND MN2.parent_id = MN1.id
                          AND RMN2.ID = 4
                          

                          )
                    )

         )
         )

FROM MENU MN1, MROLE RMN1
WHERE MN1.id = RMN1.menu_id
AND RMN1.ID = 4;
```

Below is how I see the results when run in PROD environment.

```
<MainMenu><MenuItem>
<MenuId>3</MenuId><RoleId>4</RoleId>
<MenuId>2</MenuId><RoleId>4</RoleId>
<MenuId>1</MenuId><RoleId>4</RoleId>
</MenuItem></MainMenu>
```

Below is how I see the results when ran in DEV & UAT environment.

```
<MainMenu><MenuItem>
<MenuId>1</MenuId><RoleId>4</RoleId>
<MenuId>2</MenuId><RoleId>4</RoleId>
<MenuId>3</MenuId><RoleId>4</RoleId>
</MenuItem></MainMenu>
```

The records inserted in the table are in same order but my result set is different and it causing an issue loading the data in the order of MenuID.

Comment: "The records inserted in the table are in same order" -- No, they aren't. Tables in relational databases represent relations, a special form of (multi) sets. And as sets have no order, tables don't have an order. The DBMS is free to output a result of a query in any order it "wants", unless you use an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. Aggregation functions like `xmlagg()` may have their own `ORDER BY` clause. So in this cases use the `ORDER BY` clause of `xmlagg()`.

Comment: And by the way, there is no PL/SQL involved here. Just the Oracle dialect of SQL is. Whereas PL/SQL is the procedural langue extension of Oracle.

Comment: Understood now. Can you help with the query so I fix mine by doing ORDER BY for my xmlagg().

Comment: Well, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) is the documentation that shows where to put the `ORDER BY` clause. Work out by which expression you can/want to order by (maybe `"MenuId"` ?) and insert the corresponding `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Superb.. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`XMLAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) function takes an `ORDER BY` clause. Try adding:

```
ORDER BY M2.id
```

to the end of your `XMLAGG`.

Comment: Worked. The answer posted by Sticky Bit helped.